# Add item to the end of a list regardless of length

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

I need to add a line of text to the end of a list. This list can be varying lengths, example:

```
<div id="characteristics">
  <ul>
    <li>Words</li>
    <li>More words</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I wish to target the last item in this list using JS or JQuery and add in my new line.

CSS selector for these are:

```
#characteristics ul
#characterisitcs ul li
```

Comment: $('ul').append('<li>More words words</li>');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) adds HTML at the end of an element. This should work:

```
$('#characteristics ul').append('<li>Another item</li>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `$('#characteristics > ul').append()`.

```js
var lastLI = $('#characteristics > ul').append('<li>More words words</li>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="characteristics">
  <ul>
    <li>Words</li>
    <li>More words</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that using the jQuery pseudo-selector `:last` is not very performant. From the docs: *because :last is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :last cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method.*

Answer (score 1):

Following will add the new li at the end of ul

```
$("#characteristics ul").append('<li> Your New item</li>');
```

Comment: If you want to add the text to last li then try this one $("#characteristics ul li:last-child").append('New item');

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution is use `last-child` with `after`. Or append also work which I already mention on question comment.

```js
$('ul li:last-child').after('<li>More words1</li>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="characteristics">
  <ul>
    <li>Words</li>
    <li>More words</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```